# Linear and almost linear Partial differential equations examples in Sciences

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, applications

I am interested in learning linear and almost linear PDEs of first order to describe some system or process however I want to learn by real world examples of such a application.Do you know any such system or process which is described by a linear or almost linear PDEs of first order?

Comment: Are systems of first order PDEs OK? First-order physical PDEs tend to come in systems that rarely reduce to a single first order PDE. If they do reduce down to a single PDE, it is usually second-order.

Comment: First order PDEs only.

Comment: @Gonçalo the Dirac equation is a set of PDEs since the wavefunction in the Dirac equation is a spinor.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little to broad of a topic - but if you want an example of such an equation you can look at [Navier-Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) which in certain limits/assumptions can be considered linear.

A smaller component of the above would be the [mass conservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_mass) equation which is given by
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot(\rho \mathbf{v}) = 0
$$
which is first order in derivative, a pde and is linear in terms of $\rho$.

Comment: I just hate pure math but I love applied math so by giving real world examples of systems/processes described by PDEs I can have fun while learning.

Comment: @Volpina with real-world problems, you have "real-world" problems e.g. you have to apply assumptions and simplifications :) but that is fun.

Comment: @Volpina Most pure math PDEs are idealized versions of physical PDEs. These idealized forms then get used in physics a lot because most of the physical PDEs are nonlinear, making them a pain to solve.